# App that shows what's passing in sky?

Tags: night-sky, artificial-satellite

I'm not an astronomer but I enjoy looking up at the sky.

So tonight I saw *something* moving in the sky. It looked like a star, and it was definitely not a plane (I checked in flightradar).

Is there an app, similar to flightradar for planes, that will tell me what's traveling above me in the sky?

Comment: Check out star walk 2 on the app store

Answer (score 5):

Chris Peat maintains a very sophisticated database of satellites and their visibilites at http://heavens-above.com, and there is an app available.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like Stellarium ([apk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noctuasoftware.stellarium) or [PC](http://stellarium.org/)), or Celestron's Starry Night [apk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.celestron.skyportal) for your phone (if you don't want to pay).
Hope that helps!
[Edit: I'm sorry I haven't mentioned anything on the Appstore; Stellarium is also available for [MacOS](http://stellarium.org/) and for [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/stellarium-mobile-sky-map/id643165438?mt=8), and also Celestron's Starry Night for [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/celestron-skyportal/id877780544?mt=8). This answer seems to help out on the iOS side: 
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/26205/22907]

Comment: I feel these are easy to use, esp. if you're just starting out in astronomy or something.